# Why this code does not save current tab state?

Tags: android

I need to save current tab in my tabactivity. When I'm e.g. on tab nr 3, next if open dialog and press back button it brings me back to tab1. To solve that I tried to create int currentPos to which I pass getCurrentTab() in onSaveInstanceState()/onPause and read it with setCurrenttab(currentPos) in onResume() method but it does not work :(
 I tried to change currentPost to static - then it works however this is an ugly way i suppose ;/
I would be EXTREMELY thankful for any help

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {   
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putInt(CURRENT_TAB, getTabHost().getCurrentTab());
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    currentTab = (savedInstanceState ==null) ? currentTab=0 :
           savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_TAB);
    if(currentTab >=0){
        getTabHost().setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    }
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();    
    saveState();
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();   
    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(currentTab);     
}   
private void saveState(){
    currentTab=getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a directly answer, but I deal with tabs using folowing ideas:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html:

> Note that it is important to save
>   persistent data in **onPause()**
>   instead of
>   **onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)** because the later is not part of the
>   lifecycle callbacks, so will not be
>   called in every situation as described
>   in its documentation.

Also, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState

Ex.:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveCurrentTab(getTabHost().getCurrentTab());
}

private void saveCurrentTab(int value) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt(
            PREF_KEY_CURRENT_TAB, value).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .getInt(PREF_KEY_CURRENT_TAB, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks strange?

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {   
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putInt(CURRENT_TAB, getTabHost().getCurrentTab());
}
```

You're calling the parents `onSaveInstanceState` (that does the work), Then you call a function `savestate()` that sets a var that you add to the `outstate` Bundle. But you never actually do something with that Bundle after that I think. Shouldn't you call the parent AFTER that, like so?

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {   
    saveState();
    outState.putInt(CURRENT_TAB, getTabHost().getCurrentTab());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: As long as the identifier you use in the Bundle do not collide with something Android uses internally, [the order does not matter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10342284/617559) says [CommonsWare](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)