# Super should be called at the end of the method

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    ((CustomApplication) getApplication()).detach(this);    
}
```

While generating PMD report, i got this **Error: Super should be called at the end of the method**. Normally you would eventually keep the super method at the top(First Statement) so that its parent class is first called initialized.

Comment: because it calls to save instance, how would you save your personal settings after the primary event finish ?

Comment: that`s mandatory only for Constructors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Normally you would eventually keep the super method at the top(First
>   Statement) so that its parent class is first called initialized.

The following code snippet shows you how `Activity#onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` looks like. You can see that it only saves the Bundle you passed in as an argument by calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`. So it would make no sense to call the super method before actually saving something inside the Bundle.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBundle(WINDOW_HIERARCHY_TAG, mWindow.saveHierarchyState());
    Parcelable p = mFragments.saveAllState();
    if (p != null) {
        outState.putParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG, p);
    }
    getApplication().dispatchActivitySaveInstanceState(this, outState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10342284/1035008), it doesn't matter where you call it as long as the key do not collide. They should be equivalent.

> So long as your keys do not collide (e.g., ID being the same as something Android uses internally), the two are identical.

But with that being said, Google's documentation about [The Activity's Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) shows adding this at the end. I would still follow that though:

```
// invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    out.putString(GAME_STATE_KEY, mGameState);
    out.putString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY, mTextView.getText());

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
}
```