# Call super.onSaveInstanceState(outState) in end of method?

Tags: android

I want to save state of activity. So I use method `onSaveInstanceState()`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(SOME_KEY, inCheckMode);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

The question is:

Should I call `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)` in the end of method?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17992785/3454741

Answer (score 1):

We have to store the data first.

Then we have to call the `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)` at the end.

Comment: But in official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html ---> method super.onSaveInstanceState(outState) call in the end of mehtod