# Why isn't my listfragment retaining its state?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am practicing fragments so I tried to add a ListFragment to my MainActivity. Nothing too hard, just a list where each row has a name and a number you can increase/decrease with a plus/minus button. However when I rotate the screen, all the numbers reset to 0.

MyListFragment.java

```
package randomdomain.dialogtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
    public static final String MYOBJECT_PARCELABLE_KEY = "myobject_parcelable_key";
    private MyAdapter mMyAdapter;
    private List<MyObject> mMyObjects;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        mMyObjects = fillObjects();
        mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mMyObjects);
        setListAdapter(mMyAdapter);

        return contentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        for (int i = 0; i < mMyObjects.size(); i++)
            outState.putParcelable(MYOBJECT_PARCELABLE_KEY + i, mMyObjects.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        mMyObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mMyObjects.size(); i++) {
            MyObject object = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(MYOBJECT_PARCELABLE_KEY + i);
            mMyObjects.add(object);
        }
    }

    private List<MyObject> fillObjects() {
        List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            MyObject object = new MyObject("Object " + (i + 1) + " ", 0);
            myObjects.add(object);
        }
        return myObjects;
    }
}
```

MyObject.java if needed:

```
package randomdomain.dialogtest;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MyObject implements Parcelable {
    private String mName;
    private int mValue;

    public MyObject(String name, int value) {
        mName = name;
        mValue = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        mValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0; // nothing
    }

    private MyObject(Parcel in) {
        mName = in.readString();
        mValue = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mName);
        dest.writeInt(mValue);
    }

    public static final Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new Creator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MyObject(source);
        }

        @Override
        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }
    };
}
```

And MyAdapter.java, again if needed:

```
package randomdomain.dialogtest;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<MyObject> mMyObjects;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<MyObject> objects) {
        mContext = context;
        mMyObjects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMyObjects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mMyObjects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0; //unused
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rowName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_rowname);
            holder.counter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_counter);
            holder.buttonAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
            holder.buttonSubtract = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_subtract);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.rowName.setText(mMyObjects.get(position).getName());
        holder.counter.setText(mMyObjects.get(position).getValue() + "");
        holder.buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMyObjects.get(position).setValue(Math.max(mMyObjects.get(position).getValue() - 1, 0));
                holder.counter.setText(mMyObjects.get(position).getValue() + "");
            }
        });
        holder.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMyObjects.get(position).setValue(mMyObjects.get(position).getValue() + 1);
                holder.counter.setText(mMyObjects.get(position).getValue()+ "");
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView rowName;
        public TextView counter;
        public Button buttonSubtract;
        public Button buttonAdd;
    }
}
```

And MainActivity just invokes the fragment:

```
package randomdomain.dialogtest;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyListFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Why are the values resetting even though I have extended Parcelable and saved all the values on save, and then reset the list using the saved instance state on restore?

EDIT, updated MyListFragment.java

```
package randomdomain.dialogtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
    public static final String MYOBJECT_PARCELABLE_KEY = "myobject_parcelable_key";
    private MyAdapter mMyAdapter;
    private List<MyObject> mMyObjects;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mMyObjects = fillObjects();
        }
        else {
            mMyObjects = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(MYOBJECT_PARCELABLE_KEY);
        }

        mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mMyObjects);
        setListAdapter(mMyAdapter);

        return contentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(MYOBJECT_PARCELABLE_KEY, (ArrayList<MyObject>) mMyObjects);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private List<MyObject> fillObjects() {
        List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            MyObject object = new MyObject("Object " + (i + 1) + " ", 0);
            myObjects.add(object);
        }
        return myObjects;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onCreate()` to only add a new instance of your `Fragment` if the `FragmentManager` is not able to find an existing instance:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) == null )
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyListFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now when I rotate, the entire fragment just disappears

Comment: Figured out why, changed my onsave function to `outState.putParcelableArrayList(MYOBJECT_PARCELABLE_KEY, (ArrayList<MyObject>) mMyObjects);` and then removed my restore function and in onCreateView re-assigned mMyObjects if savedInstanceState was not null.

Comment: @ArukaJ - I'm sorry and it's strange because I just re-read the relevant part in some tutorial book to make sure :( There is one other thing I just saw in your code: You call super.onSaveInstanceState() *before* putting your values to the instance state bundle. You have to call it afterwards.

Comment: why do you have to call it afterwards?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342274/call-super-onsaveinstancestatebundle-first-or-last it doesn't seem to matter?

Comment: May not matter when saving but sure matters when restoring: You get the bundle to add everything you want to save and then let the super method do its job. On restoring the other way round, because one wants certain values (e.g. in ListViews) to be already in place

Comment: I edited my post to show my updated code for the ListFragment class. Am I restoring properly or would you do it differently? I'll put the calls to super last just to be safe. I still don't quite understand what the super call is actually doing.

Comment: Do you handle restores differently / is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Also, I am still curious about this fragment fix. Why was it resetting before? Was it just making more and more and more fragments for some reason? Why wouldn't fragments automatically be destroyed when their associated activity is destroyed?

Comment: @ArukaJ - 1) in your case you are just taking your own saved values out of the bundle anyway. But I recently wanted to save/ restore state of a ListView in multiple choice mode and there it was nice to be able to query the ListView for checked items 2) It wasn't "resetting", it was discarded because you replaced it with a new instance

Comment: @ArukaJ - "why" is always difficult, but it makes sense for the FragmentManager to assist in preserving state of the activity

Comment: I actually just removed the fragment-check code and for some reason it works again. I think the problem before was that when I was restoring in my old code, I was re-setting the list object and then running a for loop using its size which will always end up being 0 `(mMyObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();  for (int i = 0; i < mMyObjects.size(); i++) {)`

Comment: @ArukaJ - hey, I was just on the point of suggesting to delete this answer - I think you are doing quite well without me. Do you really think the answer was helpful?

Comment: It was helpful for me for the sake of learning, either way, so I am okay with keeping it.

Comment: Looks like I needed this answer anyway! I was outputting `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size()` to debug things and it looks like every time I rotated the screen, it was adding another fragment, although it was saving the numbers each time. After including your code it correctly sticks to one fragment

Comment: @ArukaJ - thanks for letting me know. I'm still learning and I was starting to get a little bit puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put following code to your fragment:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, my friend, I have no possibility to test your code right now. Maybe, I'll try it later))).